# docker-compose push failed with "ERROR: unauthorized: authentication required" using Azure Registry

Tags: azure, docker, authentication, docker-compose, azure-container-registry

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose) Microsoft guide and everything works well until I run the command `docker-compose push` when I get this error:  `ERROR: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.`. None of the suggested solutions proposed in the provided links works for me.

In addition, The admin user is enabled

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: We have did a repro in our local environment by following the documentation steps,we are able to push the images to acr & able to spin up the container instance using images without any issue. As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles?tabs=azure-cli) documentation you need to have either Owner, Contributor, ACR push or ACR pull RBAC role to Pull or push an image from ACR.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT thanks for your comment. I'm the owner of both the Azure account and container registry so I could do all the actions on them. I've tried with az login, docker login but even if these commands ran successfully I'm still receiving the same error

Comment: Does the container registry has allow  public access to all networks ? can you try running az acr login --name <acrname> --debug in new session & check whether you are able to login to that registry or not

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT The container has a basic SKU so it has only public access. I think the problem is related to the name of the registry. I've created one with mixed lowercase and uppercase and then removed and recreated only lowercase. Now it works but I've created a new one with a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this solution and most of the time it works:
when you login to docke it saves the credential in cache and there is a file called config.json in this path $~:.docker/config.json check if the credential is stored there right and if there is nothing try to write the authentication credentials.

Comment: This works for me in the sense that I realize that the access token was not saved properly. Also, on Windows, docker-credential-desktop wasn't in the PATH and the credentials weren't saved in wincred store. Now It works, thanks